# How can I extract data from a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file data like below, I want to calculate the time difference between two line for each station (here PAR and PAY), I mean for example for PAR we are going to calculate '7 48 42.64 - 7 48 42.24' (7=hour, 48=minute, and 42.64 is second).

```
2006 03 20 07 47 46.7  32.314 55.843 15.5 4.5
PAR  GZ IP   7 48 42.24
PAR  GZ IPg  7 48 42.64
PAR  GZ EP   7 48 42.34
PAY  GZ IPg  7 48 57.96
PAY  GZ IP   7 48 57.59
PAY  GZ EP   7 48 57.74
```

In my code the information of first line is saved in a list named "event_REF1", and for each line to a list named "REF1_station". It search for 'IP' first and then 'IPg', for PAR there is no problem, but for PAY it make wrong result because first we have 'IPg' in data for this station.

```
if (REF1_station[0][2] == "IP "):
           earlier = (float(REF1_station[0][3])*3600+
                      float(REF1_station[0][4])*60+
                      float(REF1_station[0][5])-
                      float(event_REF1[3])*3600-
                      float(event_REF1[4])*60-
                      float(event_REF1[5]))

if (REF1_station[0][2] == "IPg"):          
           later = (float(REF1_station[0][3])*3600+
                    float(REF1_station[0][4])*60+
                    float(REF1_station[0][5])-
                    float(event_REF1[3])*3600-
                    float(event_REF1[4])*60-
                    float(event_REF1[5]))
           error = float((later - earlier)/2)
```

The result is:

PAR = 0.199999999999

PAY = 7.86

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If your lines are consistently separated by whitespace, then you can just iterate through the file to get all of the lines in a usable format and subtract whatever two lines that you want.

```
all_lines = open('your_file.txt', 'r').readlines()
all_lines = [l.split() for l in all_lines]

# Hour is index 3, Minute is 4, seconds is 5
```